# C++ boost.python cannot convert const char* to str

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I want to calculate something in C++ and return result to python. This is part of the C++ code:

```
const Mat& flow_map_x, flow_map_y;
std::vector<unchar> encoded_x, encoded_y;

flow_map_x = ...;
flow_map_y = ...;

Mat flow_img_x(flow_map_x.size(), CV_8UC1);
Mat flow_img_y(flow_map_y.size(), CV_8UC1);

encoded_x.resize(flow_img_x.total());
encoded_y.resize(flow_img_y.total());

memcpy(encoded_x.data(), flow_img_x.data, flow_img_x.total());
memcpy(encoded_y.data(), flow_img_y.data, flow_img_y.total());

bp::str tmp = bp::str((const char*) encoded_x.data())
```

The error when running python script is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

After debugging, I found that the error comes from this line:

```
bp::str tmp = bp::str((const char*) encoded_x.data())
```

I'm not good at C++. Could anyone tell me how to fix the error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't because `encoded_x.data()` is not UTF-8. You probably want [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytes.html) for a copy of the raw data:

Using `PyObject* PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(const char *v, Py_ssize_t len)`. Or you can use [`PyByteArray_FromStringAndSize`](https://docs.python.org/dev/c-api/bytearray.html#c.PyByteArray_FromStringAndSize) for a `bytearray` with the same arguments.

```
bp::object tmp(bp::handle<>(PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(
    // Data to make `bytes` object from
    reinterpret_cast<const char*>(encoded_x.data()),
    // Amount of data to read
    static_cast<Py_ssize_t>(encoded_x.size())
)));
```

In this case, you can get rid of the vector and use `flow_img_x.data` and `flow_img_x.total()` directly.

---

Or a [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memoryview.html) to not copy the data, but just access the `std::vector`s data

Using `PyObject* PyMemoryView_FromMemory(char *mem, Py_ssize_t size, int flags)`

```
bp::object tmp(bp::handle<>(PyMemoryView_FromMemory(
    reinterpret_cast<char*>(encoded_x.data()),
    static_cast<Py_ssize_t>(encoded_x.size()),
    PyBUF_WRITE  // Or `PyBUF_READ` i if you want a read-only view
)));
```

(If the vector was const, you would `const_cast<char*>(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(encoded_x.data()))` and only use `PyBUF_READ`)

You have to make sure the vector stays alive in this case though, but it won't create an unnecessary copy.

Comment: This answer perfectly solved the problem! Thank you!